# Disabling sign-ups with devise

Tags: heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, production-environment

Hi I recently came across a way to disable my sign-up button for my ROR app. The block seems to work when applied to my development environment but however crashes in production when pushed to Heroku, resulting in a code=H10 app crash. Heres the code I used-

application_controller.rb code

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def new
     flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open yet, but please check back soon'
     redirect_to root_path
   end

   def create
     flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open yet, but please check back soon'
     redirect_to root_path
   end
 end
```

Routes.rb code

```
   if Rails.env == 'production'
     devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } 
   else
     devise_for :users
   end
```